# Making a Ubuntu executable

Tags: c, linux, gcc, executable, ubuntu-9.10

i have made a program in C using the gcc compiler. Right now it has no GUI components. I am compiling it with makefile and running it in the terminal. I need to deploy it so that the executable is standalone. I want the executable to have an icon and when clicked start the program in the terminal. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The basics

(disclaimer: the following was tested with kubuntu, you might need to make some adjustments for your system)

Actually there is a standard to do that, not just for Ubuntu but for any number of *nix systems. Consult: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Howto_desktop_files:

Lets assume you have your `foo.bin` file you want to deploy. According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/), a good place to put it (if you are not using a package manager) is `/usr/local/bin/`. You will also need an icon, I will assume your artistic talent produced `foo.png`, and a good place for it might be `/usr/local/share/icons/`.

Now you need to create `foo.desktop` that might look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=My awesome fooish application 
Exec=/usr/local/bin/foo.bin
Icon=/usr/local/share/icons/foo.png
Name=Foobar
NoDisplay=false
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=1
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
```

and put it in `/usr/share/applications/`.

You might be able to use your menu editor to create such a file. Look for the generated desktop file under `~/.local/share/applications/`.

This should do the trick.

---

Another convention is to put everything under `/opt/foo/` and create symbolic links to `/usr/local/`.

## Cross DE with Portland

The [Portland project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portland_Project) provides the `xdg-*` command line utilities that make it easy to install the application's icon / menu entry / resource file, in a DE (GNOME, KDE, etc) independent way.

See the [KDE & GNOME cross-desktop development tutorial](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/kde-gnome-cross-desktop-development/) on linuxuser.co.uk.

## A better way

For deployment you should consider creating a `*.deb` package. (with your executable, `*.desktop` file and icon). There are several tutorials on this subject e.g. http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/How-to-make-deb-packages/.

Note that if you are using a package manager, the convention for file location becomes `/usr/` instead of `/usr/local/`.

## Go all the way

The next step, if you are inclined to take it, is setup your own repository, or [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas).

Comment: thanx for this link, i will do the whole -deb package in the future but for my urgent needs I just want it to open up the executable in the terminal by clicking the icon. there are  no GUI components in my code. how can this be done?

Comment: @sfactor, the "Terminal=1" option Chen included in the `foo.desktop` file should cause the program to open in a terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Chen's link gets the desktop icon and menu entry; for Ubuntu specifically (and really any Debian-derived system, for the most part), there is a whole lot of good documentation.  It's available starting at this link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Packaging?highlight=%28CategoryPackaging%24%29

Start reading at "PackagingGuide". :)

As far as running your app in a terminal under X - on Ubuntu - just run

```
x-terminal-emulator -e /path/to/your/command
```

The `x-terminal-emulator` command is managed by "update-alternatives" and will be a symlink to whatever the preferred xterm emulator is on the system.  For a Kubuntu system, it'll usually be kterm, for a regular Ubuntu system it'll likely be gnome-terminal, etc.  But you can count on x-terminal-emulator being available if X is installed.  And the `-e` option works for all of them, because it's an xterm command which they all implement for compatibility.